# Bootstrap 3.3.7 Grid system column large dose not work

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3.3.7 Column large not working as expected. but the weird part is. when i try to use bootstrap 4. it works perfectly. i don't know where the problem comes from. besides that. bootstrap 4 changes the sizes of my text. and i don't feel like upgrading.

My bootstrap is linked in my app perfectly. no issues there. i need help in why bootstrap 3.3.7 column large isn't working.

here is my code

base.html

```
<html>
```

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'assets/css/main.css' %} " />
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' %} ">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %} ">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {% static 'assets/css/responsive.css'  %} ">
<script src=" {% static 'assets/js/jquery.js'  %} "></script>
<script src=" {% static 'assets/js/script.js'   %} "></script>
```

```
{% block content %}

{% endblock content %}

<div id="footer" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <h3> Get to know us </h3>
            <div>
                <label> Work with US </label>
                <label> Work with US</label>
                <label> Work with US </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <h3> Learn with US </h3>
            <div>
                <label>Work with US </label>
                <label> Work with US </label>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <h3> Work with US </h3>
            <div>
                <label> work with us </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <h3> Find us </h3>
            <img class="img-responsve" src=" {% static 'assets/images/facebook.png'  %} ">
            <img class="img-responsve" src=" {%  static 'assets/images/twitter.png'   %} ">
            <img class="img-responsve" src=" {% static 'assets/images/instagram.jpg'  %} ">
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4 class="text-center"> title Copyright 2017 all rights reserved </h4>
</div>
```

and here is my other page that extends base.html

```
{% extends 'index/base.html' %}


{% block content %}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="top_navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
       <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand"> title</a>
            </div>
            <div style="margin: 10px;" class="navbar navbar-right">
                <button class="btn btn-success"> 4648564864</button>
                <button class="btn btn-info"> Signup </button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary"> login </button>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="col-lg-4">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <h3 id="test"> Testing </h3>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <h3 id="test"> Testing  </h3>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

my other django files work well with no problem. i don't understand. someone help!

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by _does not work_. How does it work? How do you expect it to work?

Comment: as you can see i am trying to have two columns side by side. but the output is different. the columns are on top of each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns get on top of each other when the window width is not enough for them. So if you write `col-lg-6` and the window width is less then the `lg` breakpoint's width, those columns will placed on top of each other.

Bootsrap 3 and 4 have different breakpoints, that's why you see difference among them. ([Bootstrap 3 breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options) and [Bootstrap 4 breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options))

Try to use `col-md-6` where you wrote `col-lg-6`.

Comment: it works well with that. but my other html files use the col-lg and it works perfectly